# How can I skip a file when using os.listdir that has nothing written in it

Tags: python, file, python-2.x, os.walk

I am trying to go through all my files in a directory and make another text file that will eventually allow me to make plots out of my data.  Some of the VariantLine# files do not contain any information in them because those variants were not found in any of my strains.  When I start to iterate through my for loop, it says that my list indexing is out of range, but this is happening in the files that don't have anything written in them.  I have over 10,000 VariantLine# files, so I don't want to go through each one individually and get rid of all of the ones that had nothing written in them.  I just want to parse through the ones that do contain information written in them, since these are the ones that will provide me with the information I need to make plots.  The only information I have found thus far has to deal with just skipping a line with no information, not a whole file.

```
for files in os.listdir("/nobackup/rogers_research/tmiorin/DsantRNAproject"):
    if re.search("^VariantLine", files):
        filename=files
        filenumber=filename[11:]
        print filenumber
        for line in filename:
            stuff=line.split()
            strain=stuff[0]
            chrom=stuff[1]
            posone=stuff[2]
            postwo=stuff[3]
```

Essentially my problem is that I need a way to parse through only the files that have something written in them, so ideally I need to put a line of code before "for line in filename" that will read the files and only continue with the for loop if it actually has stuff printed to it.  I can't seem to find any information online, so if anyone happens to know what I could put I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: Are you sure about the reason of your error? In your code, you actually never open the file to read it. `for line in filename` iterates over the characters in the filename string

Comment: @Valentino, my same initial concern. This isn't even opening the files.

Comment: I ended up printing out filename and realized that's what it was doing.  Once I opened up the files it was able to work.  Thank you for helping!  That wasn't something I had realized initially.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
for files in os.listdir("/nobackup/rogers_research/tmiorin/DsantRNAproject"):
    if re.search("^VariantLine", files):
        filename=files
        filenumber=filename[11:]
        print filenumber
        for line in filename:
            if (not line==""):
                stuff=line.split()
                strain=stuff[0]
                chrom=stuff[1]
                posone=stuff[2]
                postwo=stuff[3]
```

if (not line==""): checks whether the line is not empty, and if you wish you can check even line is not equal to "\n" if this don't work

Comment: There are non-empty lines that would also produce this error. Why not test `len(stuff)` after `line.split()` and make sure that there are enough items?

Comment: do you mean : if (len(line.split())>=4):

Comment: he can try it also but if he is sure that empty lines are creating problems, why should he waste computations finding split for all and then length.

Comment: Note that they are *not even opening the file*. `files` is just a single filename, not the *contents* of the named file.

Comment: I agree..file isn't even being opened. This just iterates over the filename...this shouldn't be the solution

Comment: i just tried to correct the given code, and give some intution how to go further with it.   it had helped the asker as he had accepted my answer. i know it seems wierd it isn't opening the file.

Comment: maybe his data is in the file name itself maybe.

Answer (score 0):

when looping through the files, first check their size and only work on those with size > 0 :

```
if os.stat(filename).st_size > 0:
    <work>
```

Comment: `os.scandir()` saves you some of the trouble by giving you an `os.DirEntry` object which contains a `.stat()` member method. Of course, that still ends up calling `os.stat(...)` internally, but it has the benefit of caching the `stat_result` object. While that caching may not be particularly useful to the OP of this question, it might be useful in other scenarios for future readers. In terms of relevance for this OP, we can actually exclude all files smaller than 7 bytes, since the OP wants 4 data members in the file. (That would be 4 bytes minimum for data, and 3 bytes for delimiters.)

Comment: thanks..so find the size of a file with no data (if it is not 0)

Answer (score 0):

This code should not only be checking the length of the return result from the split, but it can also optimize itself by avoiding opening empty files in the first place like so:

```
DATA_FILE_PREFIX = 'VariantLine'
# We expect each line of the file to contain 4 records and we will separate them
# with a split operation.
# Split, by default, tries to split on whitespace. Therefore, each file should
# contain a minumum of (4 data bytes + 3 delimiting bytes) = 7 total bytes
MIN_DATA_FILE_BYTE_SIZE = 7

# Get contents form directory as os.DirEntry objects
dir_contents = os.scandir("/nobackup/rogers_research/tmiorin/DsantRNAproject")

# Filter directory contents to ensure that we only look at FILES, whose names
# match our known file prefix, and whose size in bytes is greater than min.
data_files_in_dir = [
    file_result
    for file_result in dir_contents
    if (file_result.is_file()
        and file_result.name.startswith(DATA_FILE_PREFIX)
        and file_result.stat().st_size >= MIN_DATA_FILE_BYTE_SIZE)
]

# Just calling this out explicitly so we can avoid calling len() each iteration
LEN_OF_FILE_PREFIX = len(DATA_FILE_PREFIX);
# Open all data files and read them.
for file_result in data_files_in_dir:
    file_name = file_result.name
    file_number = file_name[LEN_OF_FILE_PREFIX:]
    with open(file_name, 'r') as data_file_handle:
        for line in data_file_handle:
            stuff=line.split()
            # You might want to modify this condition to be 'length == 4'
            # Not sure how much you value your data quality, but in some
            # circumstances, I might be alarmed if I had more than 4 records in
            # a given line, as that might indicate data corruption and/or an
            # error in the collection method.
            if(len(stuff) >= 4):
                strain=stuff[0]
                chrom=stuff[1]
                posone=stuff[2]
                postwo=stuff[3]
                do_something_with_data(strain, chrom, posone, postwo)
    # End open(file)
# End of for-loop over directory results
```

This approach utilizes pre-conditions to avoid opening empty files **and** files that logically cannot contain enough data to be of value, which optimizes I/O. Furthermore, it adds a check after splitting the file to ensure that the data inside of a given line contained at least four members. Also, this solution does away with RegEx matching the filename, which is highly inefficient if the code just needs to confirm that the filename starts with a sequence of characters.